Why does BashFAQ #50 not recommend using eval?
According to https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050
...putting bash commands in shell variables for subsequent execution is a Very Bad Idea.
But what's bad about the following?
#!/bin/bash

cmd="for i in \$(seq 3); do echo 'a' 'b  c' 'd' \$i | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'; done"

eval "$cmd"

It seems to work pretty well, even preserving whitespace, allowing a for loop and allowing a pipe.
Granted it's not that fast, but is bash really about speed?

What kind of answer are you looking for? eval should be avoided at all cost. It'll work, but when replacing seq 3 with another data-source, it's getting scary already.

A lot of the discussion on why not parse ls is equally relevant here. The wiki doesn't say putting commands in variables is bad because it's impossible, it says that because it's very hard to write quality code that way (readable, maintainable, safe in the face of malformed/malicious input) and there's no benefit to it over putting that code into a function.

It has no benefits and several downsides compared to the equivalent function.

If you're reading the BashFAQ, see #48, which is directly on point for why eval is discouraged.

BTW, in addition to everything else (in the other comments, the linked duplicate, BashFAQ #48, etc) I'd also add that the very fact that you had to add a backslash before each $ is bad -- it's an extra step that if left out results in potentially-subtle, potentially-security-impacting bugs that folks need to audit for on a code read. One thing that makes a practice bad is fragility -- ease of doing it wrong by mistake.

""eval" is a common misspelling of "evil". "

Many things are bad about that. It is hard to read (and editors won’t syntax-highlight it), hard to reuse, hard to modify safely (once external variables are introduced, which is bound to happen).
cmd() {
  local -ar tokens=(a 'b  c' d)
  local -i i
  for ((i = 0; i < 3; ++i)); do
    echo "${tokens[@]^^}" "$i"
  done
}

cmd


Might also want local i to avoid the counter from leaking into global scope.
